# Change ListView's current index background color and not override other "states"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

My Qt Quick Control 2 app is using Material Dark Theme. I would like to change background color of selected item in `ListView`. I know that I can do this in item delegate:

```
SwipeDelegate {
    id: delegate
    checkable: true
    spacing: 0
    width: parent.width

    background: Rectangle {
        color: index===currentIndex ? "red" : "transparent"
    }
```

But with change above I'm losing defaults padding etc and also Material's radial animation on press and hold state is missing too. Is it possible to just change color only of selected item and keep original behavior for other states of item? Seems that I must reimplement missing things by my self

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider to implement highlight. The following worked for me:

```
ListView {
    // ... Your stuff ...

    highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue";  }
    focus: true
}
```

Comment: Indeed your solution does work but only if you use simple delegate for `ListView`, for example `ItemDelegate`. In my case, I'm using `SwipeDelegate` and highlight is covered. Tried to play with Z order, `highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue";  z: 1}` result that only first item is highlighted (but I don't see the text), `highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue";  z: 2}` result that all selected items are highlighted but without item's text